# SQLEXPRESS Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, sql-server-express, yellow-screen-of-death

I deployed an ASP.NET MVC app using MSDeploy and ran into this problem i tried every solution that i found over internet and i still can't get this working it's a small basic MVC 2 app that I built while learning. 
so..

1. how do you get this thing running under IIS7?
2. what is the exact problem?

**Screenshot**
http://screencast.com/t/0tBZoHoN
[image]

Comment: error message looks clear to me. it seems to be trying to create the DB in the users folder...

Comment: What user is the service running as?

Comment: i didn't changed anything it's a default IIS install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you take a look at this question?
https://serverfault.com/questions/1886/failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server
Maybe it can help you.